# How to dynamically increase the height of a <div /> based on the contents?

Tags: css, html, height

I have a div on a page that I need to put content into. Sometimes the content is a few lines high, and sometimes the content is more than the screen height with varying sizes in between.

There is content below the div so I need that content to be pushed down appropriately, so the content below is always right below the div.

Basically, it looks as follows:

```
<div id="MainContentArea"><!-- my content --></div>

<div id="BottomContentArea"><!-- pre-existing content --></div>
```

It's easy for me to specify a height for the #MainContentArea but I want the height to be adjusted dynamically. Can somebody please show me how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: As long as the content isn't floated, the container should be pushed down automatically already, shouldn't it?

Comment: Are you dealing with floats and the container not containing them properly?

Comment: it would be great to see your CSS code for these IDs. By default DIV elements will expand based on content. But I assume you're using absolute: positioning with a specific height and width. We need to see your CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resizing vertically to fit the content is the expected behavior. If you have specified floats somewhere in your css you may need to clear them:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: This turned out to be it - I wasn't using floats as was suggested here and elsewhere. however, I was getting the content of `MainContentArea` back from an asynchronous request. I specified its CSS as `clear: both;` and it did the trick.

Comment: I love stackoverflow, clear:both did the trick for me as well.

Answer (score 11):

Don't specify a height, and the div will automatically resize with the contents.

If you need a minimum size, there is a CSS property called `min-height` that sets the minimum height of the div.

Comment: please note ie6 only supports `min-height` for TD's... although ie6 should just die already

Answer (score 3):

`#MainContentArea` will always expand dynamically since its height is assigned as auto.

Since both have the same width, `#BottomContentArea` will be pushed down.

Instead of percentage, use exact widths.

```
<div id="MainContentArea" style="float:left;height:auto;width:100%;">
<!-- my content -->
</div>

<div id="BottomContentArea" style="float:left;height:auto;width:100%;s">
<!-- pre-existing content -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you did here?

Comment: @JonasG.Drange "MainContentArea" will always expand dynamically since its height is assigned as auto. since both have the same width "BottomContentArea" will be pushed down. Instead of percentage use exact width if required (make sure u have a div which contain both these divs with same width  ). hope u know this.. and btw sorry for the *s

Answer (score 0):

The height should resize automatically, and the bottom DIV should be pushed down in accordance with this height.