# Not getting correct height of a div after adding child elements dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I have a main DIV with id say div1.
I added some child elements(divs, tables, etc) in div1 in the document load event. But when I check the height of div1 after adding child elements the height not changing. 
Please help me...

```
//HTML code for main DIV
    <div id='div1' style="height: 10px">&nbsp;</div>

//Javascript in Document Load event
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
var child1 = document.createElement('div');
child1.setAttribute('style', 'height:50px');
div1.appendChild(child1);
var height = $("#div1").height();
alert(height);//value of height is 10px NOT 50px
```

Comment: Try `height:auto` on `div1`

Comment: Thanks for answer Akshay. Putting auto for parent works but in my project I should add n number of child elements as a tree(one under another child) with different heights. So is any other solution without putting height auto please?

Comment: Or you might try `min-height:10px;` on `div1`

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504246/how-to-dynamically-increase-the-height-of-a-div-based-on-the-contents

Answer (score 0):

Ther is a typo, replace your variable height with `var height = $("#div1").height();`

Comment: Thanks. That was my mistake when write here. Edited that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/jzeg0k4u/

```
//HTML
<div id='div1'>&nbsp;</div>
//CSS
#div1{
    height: auto;
    min-height: 10px;
}
//JS
//Javascript in Document Load event
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
var child1 = document.createElement('div');
child1.setAttribute('style', 'height:50px');
div1.appendChild(child1);
var height = $("#div1").height();
alert(height);//value of height is 10px NOT 50px
```

try not to use inline style attribute.

--Edit--
You can optimize your js like below

```
var div1 = $('#div1');
var child1 = document.createElement('div');
$(child1).css('height', '50px');
div1.append(child1);
var height = div1.height();
alert(height);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

`child1.style.height= "50px";`

OR

`child1.setAttribute("style", "height: 50px;");`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have given the `height: 10px` which is fixed so it will not change. Instead of using height use `min-height: 10px`. In this way if new child are added the height will automatically increase.